How to check if webhdfs is working properly, and debug it
I am having a Hadoop setup on my machine, and I want to use Python hdfs library to send a file.
On my localhost:9870 I am seeing a hadoop user interface, which works nicely.
But, when I go to Utilities -> Browse File System, I am seeing this error:
Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error

When I go to:
http://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS
I receive following error:
HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
URI:    /webhdfs/v1/
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
SERVLET:    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-40499e4f
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4d148bd [in thread "qtp187457031-25"]
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector

As far as I see webhdfs is enabled, but I am not sure what can be the problem.
